# Как убрать кнопку "Предыдущая шаблон"

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Как убрать кнопку "Предыдущая шаблон" со страницы сайта?
Elementor Pro
Тема: Astra
[image: Выделенная кнопка]

Comment: Это называется пагинацией. Скорее всего, если нельзя убрать елементором(точнее не он генерирует ссылку), то даный код прописан в темплейте темы(шаблона), в даном случае тогда надо убрать соответсвующий код из шаблона темы.

Comment: Сейчас поищу и отпишусь на этот счет.

Comment: Увы, дело отнюдь не в теме, страницы созданные через встроенный редактор такого не выдают. Но у меня появилась идея (эдакий костыль) перенести страницы с elementor во встроенный редактор страниц. Не знаю, можно ли считать это решением, но все же

Comment: вообщето, любая страница(точней темплейт) может иметь пагинацию. Я бы перепроверил детальней.

Comment: Вообще, я понял почему эта пагинация не убирается. Сам elementor это конструктор для создания шаблонов, а пагинация здесь является элементом интерфейса самого elementor, так что страницы в любом случае придется переносить страницы в встроенный редактор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пагинация является частью самого интрефейса Elementor, сама проблема возникла из-за моей невнимательности. Все эти страницы были созданы как шаблоны для страниц, поэтому в любом случае придется переносить их, так что работы у меня прибавится. Не повторяйте моих ошибок.